# ssh4 LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2, lazy-evaluation

here is stack:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session 
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164) 
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:285) 
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
cn.btttech.entity.Department_$_javassist_10.getPrivileges(Department_$_javassist_10.java) 
cn.btttech.service.comm.TableColumnsService.list(TableColumnsService.java:44) 
cn.btttech.service.comm.TableColumnsService$FastClassByCGLIB$3753c7f6.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

the solution I tried:
1.web.xml

```
<filter> 
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name> 
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name> 
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
    </filter> 

    <filter-mapping> 
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name> 
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    </filter-mapping>
```

in front of configuration of struts2
2.TableColumnsService class

```
@Service("tableColumnsService") 
@Transactional(readOnly = true) 
public class TableColumnsService extends AbstractService<TableColumns>{ 

@Transactional(readOnly = true) 
public Set<TableColumns> list(User user, Menu menu) { 

System.out.println("MenuName:"+menu.getMenuName()); 

Set<TableColumns> tableColumnsesMenu = menu.getTableColumnses(); 
Department department = user.getDepartment();
Set<Privilege> privileges = department.getPrivileges();Here is error line
```

3.spring transaction

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/> 
    <!-- TransactionManager -->  
    <bean id="transactionManager"  
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"  
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

4.user class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id") 
@Lazy(false) 
public Department getDepartment() { 
return this.department; 
}
```

I'm confused so much , any suggestion would be appreciate. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are trying to access a collection which is detached...

Remove the `@Lazy(false)` and try with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

If this is working revert the changes and add Hibernate.initizlize(department);

Also there is an error in you mapping too..
One user can have many departments so in that case in user class department should be a Set instead of one object..

Try the same with privileges too..
department object is not initialized to get privileges..